# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in Node.js on direct call

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is pretty crazy, so I thought I'd come here and see what I'm doing wrong. I'm running Node v.2.1.1 on Amazon 64-bit Linux 2016.03, and I get the strangest error. I keep getting a TypeError on forEach, and I have no idea why. Other code in this server works just fine, but this one loop crashes.

Stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at /var/app/current/server.js:59:93
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at buildResizeTasks (/var/app/current/server.js:40:29)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:412:9)
```

Here's the actual function call:

```
[ { width: 90, suffix: "_s" }, { width: 145, suffix: "_m" }, { width: 640, suffix: "" }].forEach(
    size => {
        logger.log("info", "build resize tasks 6")
        data.tasks.push({
            Height: "",
            Width: size.width,
            OriginalLocation: data.payload.FolderLocation+"/originals/"+data.payload.FileName,
            SaveLocation: data.payload.FolderLocation+"/"+fileParts.name+size.suffix+fileParts.ext,
            OriginalBucket: data.payload.OriginBucket,
            SaveBucket: bucket
        })
    }
)
```

The logger is Winston, data.payload comes from hapi's request.payload, fileParts comes from path's path.parse, bucket comes from the data.payload object. All of the values in payload have been validated as not being null/undefined, and data.tasks is an array. What am I missing?

The "build resize tasks 6" line does not debug, and the forEach is on line 59.

---

Edit: Assigning the array to a variable beforehand fixes the error:

```
var sizes = [ { width: 90, suffix: "_s" }, { width: 145, suffix: "_m" }, { width: 640, suffix: "" }]
    sizes.forEach(
           ...
```

I'm prepared to live with this behavior, because I'm getting the job done, but now I'm utterly confused why this code confuses Node, but doesn't confuse Chrome, which runs on the same engine.

Comment: can you add entire file ? I mean code. From looking at code I dont see any issue. Is there any other forEach in file?

Comment: @RohitShedage The code in its entirety is part of a project for work. However, I did just assign the array to a variable and then iterated over it with no other modifications, and it worked.